# alternative way of filtering dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops

Community! It´s a long explanation but a 'simple' question! I have this following df:

```
d = {'name': ['john', 'mary', 'james'], 'area':[['IT', 'Resources', 'Admin'], ['Software', 'ITS', 'Programming'], ['Teaching', 'Research', 'KS']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[image]

---

My goal is to filter words from column 'area' which length is > 3. So, it would look like:

[image]

---

There are two ways I learned to approach this situation:

1. `df['area']=df['area'].map(lambda x: [e for e in x if len(e)>3])`
2. def g(x):

   ```
    return [e for e in x if len(e)>3]

    df['area']=df['area'].map(g)
   ```

In both cases, It works.

---

In terms of learning I am approaching this situation without using lambda function but iterating over rows and then apply func.

This is what I get

[image]

The desired output is not the same. Could anyone please show me what is needed to be done in my code so it gets the desired output?

I really appreciate all the support I´m receiving so far! thanks!!

Comment: You are early returning the first matched element in your function. Instead you should create a list, append the element that satisfies the condition to the list and return the list.

Comment: `return e` exits the function, thereby only returning the first occurrence where `len(e) > 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning the first element that is longer than 3. Try this:

```
def f(x):
    answer = []
    for e in x:
        if len(e)>3:
            answer.append(e)
    return answer
```

But even better, trying a more pythonic way:

```
def f(x):
    return [e for e in x if len(e)>3]
```

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` as a few `.str` methods you can use one is `.str.len()`

first you need to explode your dataframe so we can apply an operation across the entire df instead of iterating on each element.

```
df1 = df.explode('area')

df1[df1['area'].str.len() > 3]\
            .groupby('name',as_index=False)\
            .agg(list)
```

---

```
   name                     area
0  james     [Teaching, Research]
1   john       [Resources, Admin]
2   mary  [Software, Programming]
```

Comment: Hi, Umar!. Thanks so much for your response!! I didn´t know that I could approach as you showed!! I will learrn more for .str methods! Thankss!!!